# Monitor site for changes and email daily

Tags: svn, cron, inotify

I would like to monitor several sites for changes to basically notifiy me when files are added are changed. This so I can quickly reverse hacks when they happen or changes made by other users that were wrong. I read quite a bit on the subject and I initially understood I should use [incron or incrontab](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=why&lang=en) for this.

The issue is that incron does not search recursively, I did not find a script that emails changes when detected and that I am not a Bash star as of yet so that hacking is slow.

#### Searching recursively using incrontab

I did find some could some help at Cybercity to search recursively. This was an article more written for using rsynch when changes are made. I just need to get an email when changes have been made so I can do something about it if need be. Either that or changes logged and pinged at an email address.

#### Code in Progress

The code I am trying to make and run every day would be something like:

```
find /home/user/site.com -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} echo "{} IN_CLOSE_WRITE,IN_CREATE,IN_DELETE email-me '*.tmp' -a /home/user/site.com/ user@www2.example.com:/home/user/site.com/" > /etc/incron.d/webroot.conf
```

#### Emailing the changes

What I could be needing to figure out is how to send an email with changes made and to send these changes once a day at a certain hour. Emailing it was sort of discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/484631/trying-to-monitor-file-folder-changes-on-the-server-and-send-notification-what). Code for it was `mail -s "server change" email@emailaddress.com` But what I need is to make it work in my snippet. Sending it daily is probably like a regular crontab so the main issue is printing all in an email and sending it.

#### Issues

So my question is, how can I fix this script to email changes and how can I make it run on a daily basis?

#### Update

I was told I could achieve all this with (Sub)version and a cronjob as well. Subversion can be used to compare a local or dev copy to the live copy and with a cronjob I can schedule the diff report to be sent to me. I do know how I can make a cronjob and I have the follow setup

```
svn.site.com with repo
dev.site.com with beta site/backup site
site.com live site
```

Any changes I make on dev I can push the live site using svn update.

But what I need now is a script to send me changes made on the live site compared to the repo or dev site. I am reading about diff [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.diff.html).  How can I now compare the live site to the repo and send the difference in an email to me?

@tripleee told me `cd /path/to/directory; svn diff | mail -s "diff" you@example.com` as a cronjob would do. I am looking into this.

Comment: @tripleee I do have SVN on my Dreamhost VPS and also [SVN2FTP](http://svn2ftp.com) . Are you talking about using cron to SVN in the fly and diff at night to check the difference? Any scripts that I could use as a template? As mentioned I am pretty green when it comes to Bash and beginner level SVN..

Comment: @tripleee Seems to work like a charm! Thanks. What if the owner of the svn repo is different from the  owner of the live site? I guess with cron running as root that will be OK? If you would add this as an answer with the a schedule time for 9 AM server time I will be happy to upvote it and accept it.

Comment: Why would you run that as root?  Anyway, posted a slightly refactored answer as requested.  I will proceed to remove my comments and recommend you remove yours as well to keep this topic focused.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the output in a file, run a daily regular crontab to email you that file and replace it with an empty file?

As such, inotify might be overkill - just use a version control system and run its diff function every morning (you should have version control anyhow, right?):

```
00 09 * * * cd /path/to/directory && svn diff
```

Put this in the crontab of the user who owns `/path/to/directory`; this user will receive the diff as an email from Cron.  If you want to redirect it elsewhere, try setting the `MAILTO` variable in the crontab, or use `svn diff | mail -s "server change" user@elsewhere.example.com`

This solution presupposes that the live site is an actual `svn` checkout, not e.g. the result of `svn export`.  Some sites disallow this for security reasons (if the live site gets hacked, the hacker can access your repo!) but as I understand from your comments, that is not the case here.

Comment: I was sort of running, but then when I made changes on the production site I got error like `svn: Directory 'wp-content/plugins/latest-twitter-updates-with-date-and-time/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing` and `svn: Directory 'wp-content/themes/genesis/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing` and I cannot seem to be able to get rid of them. Even `find . -name 'lock' -exec rm -v {} \;` did not work...

Comment: Looks like you removed or corrupted the working copy. Maybe move it aside and check out a fresh copy in its place.

Comment: What if I want to use a new repo based on live site (now working copy)? How do I remove svn data from live site not to pollute new repo based on production or live site? Perhaps `find . -type d -name .svn -print0 | xargs -0 rm -fr` ?

Comment: That disables all SVN operations, so your site is no longer a live `svn` checkout.  If you want to check in what you have on the live site, `svn ci` is the command for that.

Comment: Cannot get rid of this blockade saying it is working copy admin is missing http://pastebin.com/ib6Gr1Gp